# insert the hierarchical numbering of the position inside the text for example for a `paragraph`

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I want to be able to insert the hierarchical numbering of the position inside the text anywhere in the text (for example for a `paragraph`)

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{chapter}
    \section{section}
    \subsection{subsection}
    \paragraph{Definition} blabla
    \subsection{Remark}
    blabla
\end{document}
```

with following output:

[image]

What I would like to write is either

`Definition 1.1.1.1 blabla`

`1.1.1.1 Definition blabla`

I'm aware that because there is additional `subsubsection` between `subsection` and `paragraph` the numbering would be `1.1.1.0.1` instead of `1.1.1.1`. That would be also ok

Comment: You want to write the numbers manually, i.e. not rely on LaTeX's numbering system?  By the way: `1.1.1.0.1` would look ugly

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, no I don't want to write the number manually, I want it to be automatic. This is why the ugly answer `1.1.1.0.1` might happen

Comment: Omitting a sectioning level such as `\subsubsection` is an logical error, however. But try `\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}\counterwithin{paragraph}{subsection}`

Answer (score 1):

Omitting a sectioning level is a logical error actually, it breaks the hierarchy.

However, it can be done by removing the counter resetting for `paragraph` on `subsubsection` level and reestablishing it on `subsection` level.

In order to prevent the lines in ToC indented too much, `\l@paragraph` should be changed as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}

\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}
\counterwithin{paragraph}{subsection}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\makeatletter
\let\l@paragraph@old\l@paragraph
\let\l@paragraph\l@subsubsection
\let\l@subparagraph\l@paragraph@old% Just in case...
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\paragraph{Definition} blabla
\subsection{Remark}
blabla
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @christianhupfer. Is it then possible to place that number **in the middle** of the text

Comment: Possible, but tedious. Most likely you should use something like an theorem environment rather for `Definition 1.1.1.1` -- that's much better, in my point of view, i.e. `\begin{definition}...\end{definition}`